# Auditing use of system vars in Win7

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I was wondering if there is a way to mount some sort of a hook on a system variable in Win7 which would allow me to trace which application and at what time referenced it.  I would like to know this in order to clean up some unused environment variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, this is not possible as every application (process) gets a private copy of environment variables block from its parent process. 
There is a way to audit modification of system/user wide environment variable, but not reading a value of a variable.

Hope that helps.